# Winnovative pdf converter design issue?

Tags: css, asp.net, winnovative

we are using PDF converter from Winnovative. Recently our browsers were upgraded to IE10 from IE7. hence the html css design of the pages being converted to PDF are distorted.   Using the meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" the aspx  looks good in IE10 but the same page when converted to PDF is not in the same way. How can i make the Winnovative use the browser emulation of the aspx page.  Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to fix your CSS with a different objective in mind, I'm afraid. Winnovative is based off WebKit, which is the same rendering engine as Chrome and Safari. If your page displays correctly in Chrome and Safari, it will display correctly in your PDF.